# How to get VerificationStatus from a PHP object?

Tags: php, api, amazon-web-services

How can I obtain the VerificationStatus from this PHP object?

```
    Guzzle\Service\Resource\Model Object
    (
        [structure:protected] => 
        [data:protected] => Array
            (
                [VerificationAttributes] => Array
                    (
                        [user@gmail.com] => Array
                            (
                                [VerificationStatus] => Success
                            )

                    )

                [ResponseMetadata] => Array
                    (
                        [RequestId] => csdgdf62-fdsg-dfgdf-23-bf91f933ab69
                    )

            )

    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered the answer in Amazon SES docs:

When the data is accessed with:

```
$result = $client->getIdentityVerificationAttributes(array(
    // Identities is required
    'Identities' => array($email)
));
```

you can access VerificationStatus at:

```
$result['VerificationAttributes'][$email]['VerificationStatus']
```

and therefore check it with:

```
if($result['VerificationAttributes'][$email]['VerificationStatus']=='Success'){
    // verification status was successful
}
```

Comment: It seems like you should read this section in the AWS SDK for PHP User Guide about handling results: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/guide/latest/quick-start.html#response-models.